# Understanding GIT workflow a little better

Tags: git

Im wondering if someone can help me understand the best way for me to implement git source control on my project.

I have been working on a project now for 7 months, on a live server ... I dont really want to do this anymore as if i do something a little wrong, the site goes wonky.

So i have decided to git it all ... i have been reading up and watching videos on it and i think i have the general flow of how i should do things. but some things still go over my head.

The site basically allows users to upload pictures of shoes to their profile and display them in a collection, so images are being uploaded all the time and you can imagine that the image storage is quite big now.

So, on my local laptop (mac) i have installed mamp and git, i have FTP'ed to the live server and dumped all the files on my laptop, now i have a working website on my laptop, that all works fine. I have signed up an account with BitBucket which will host my repo for the time being.

I run the git init on my laptop, and all that works perfect.

Update some files, commit changes and push it to BitBucket is fine.

Ok, so heres the thing im concerned about ... if i do a git init on the live server and do a pull it will download all files from BitBucket .... but what about the images? any new images that have been uploaded to the live server by users will be overridden by the images in BitBucket is this right?

Im a litte confused, any help would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Add the directory that the uploaded images are in - to your .gitignore file, handle those outside of git

Comment: @house9 - Thanks for that, but if the images are vital to making the site run locally and test, then they have to be part of the repo so when moving to another machine it works straight away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use git to track only the source code of your site, not the customer data (images, data, other stuff). Add the images directory in your .gitignore file so that they won't be added to the repository.

The customer data should be backed up separately...

Comment: Thanks for your response, if i add the directories to the .gitignore file, then when i go to pull the source to another machine to work on, then the whole app will fall over because it cant find images or directories?

Comment: it is very likely... that's why you should have some test images in your repo. You usually don't test on the live data (which in your case is huge). When you want to update the code on your server you should do a `rsync` or just copy the files through ftp...

Comment: Is that instead of doing a git pull on the live server to download updates?

Comment: yes... but if you insist you can do a `git pull` on the server... it wouldn't be wrong.

Comment: Interesting ... Thanks for the info .... So its not really good as a backup system? it does take time to get up and running on a local machine, its not as simple as cloning a repo and get started working

Comment: I prefer git pull verse FTP for deployment. Also consider storing the uploaded files on Amazon S3, you set up your dev config to point to a different bucket than the production config.

Comment: @house9 - Thats an interesting comment, all images would be stored on S3 meaning that i could put the entire website structure under source control?

Comment: Yes, and to clarify we are talking about only the user uploaded images, it is user content: similiar to the data in your database, which is not under source control either (but hopefully backed up)

Comment: That sounds like the perfect solution .... now to figure how to do S3 hahaha .. thanks :)